# Array items modified before mapping. Please explain how

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a JavaScript class and I have a JSON object variable called "options" where I'm modifying the "items" array of that variable.

```
class CustomDropdown {

    constructor(opt) {
        this.options = {
            element: opt.element,
            name: opt.name,
            multiChoice: opt.multiChoice === true,
            callbacks: [],
            items: opt.items.map(i => {
                const text = i.text || "";
                const it = {
                    text: text,
                    value: (i.value || text).replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\_\-\ ]/g, "").trim(),
                    selected: (i.selected === true && i.selected !== undefined)
                };

                console.log("json obj in map func:", it);
                return it;
            })
        };

        console.log("after:", this.options.items);

        //this seems to be the function messing things up.
        this.fixSelectedItems();
    }

    fixSelectedItems() {
        const itemsBefore = this.options.items;
        this.debug("Fixing the items, before:", itemsBefore);
        if(!this.options.multiChoice) {
            let hasSelectedItem = false;
            this.options.items = this.options.items.map(i => {
                if(i.selected === true) {
                    if(selectedItem === null) {
                        hasSelectedItem = true;
                    } else {
                        i.selected = false;
                    }
                }
                return i;
            });

            if(!hasSelectedItem) {
                this.options.items[0].selected = true;
            }
        }
        this.debug("Fixed the items, after:", this.options.items);
    }

}
```

So, not calling `this.fixSelectedItems()` prints in dev tools console the following:

```
json obj in map func: {text: "hm...", value: "hm", selected: false}
json obj in map func: {text: "none", value: "wow", selected: false}
json obj in map func: {text: "omg again", value: "omg again", selected: false}
after: [{text: "hm...", value: "hm", selected: false}, {text: "none", value: "wow", selected: false}, {text: "omg again", value: "omg again", selected: false}]
```

But calling `this.fixSelectedItems()`, AFTER logging to console the `this.options.items` sets the first JSON object in the `this.options.items` selected to true... But it should say false for all of them until this function is called, if that makes sense.

```
json obj in map func: {text: "hm...", value: "hm", selected: true}
json obj in map func: {text: "none", value: "wow", selected: false}
json obj in map func: {text: "omg again", value: "omg again", selected: false}
after: [{text: "hm...", value: "hm", selected: true}, {text: "none", value: "wow", selected: false}, {text: "omg again", value: "omg again", selected: false}]
Fixing the items, before: [{text: "hm...", value: "hm", selected: true}, {text: "none", value: "wow", selected: false}, {text: "omg again", value: "omg again", selected: false}]
Fixing the items, after: [{text: "hm...", value: "hm", selected: true}, {text: "none", value: "wow", selected: false}, {text: "omg again", value: "omg again", selected: false}]
```

Sorry if this seems a bit messy but I'm just confused.
Why is calling `this.fixSelectedItems()` AFTER modifying the array before the function is called? Is it the array mapping?

BTW `this.debug` is just console.log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objects displayed in your log are references to the actual objects themselves, so if the logged object is edited prior to viewing the log, it is will display the current version of that object, not the state it was in at the time of logging.

If you change your console logs to the following (to "deep clone" the object at that state in time, instead of logging a reference to it) you will see the logs you expect. Though its worth noting that the issue is only with the logs, your code will work as intended.

```
console.log("json obj in map func:", JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(it)));
```